# Reject windows 10 free upgrade with Microsoft Windows Server Update Services 3.0 SP2?

Tags: windows, wsus

is it possible to reject windows 10 free upgrade with Microsoft Windows Server Update Services 3.0 SP2 ?
I would like to block every possible free upgrade in my network, and I need to prevent the upgrade on several windows 7 pro and windows 8.1 pro machines.
Can it be done with wsus 3.0 sp2?
Would you recommend that course of action?
Thank You.

Comment: Don't give your users administrative permissions on their machines.

Comment: Wish I was the one that could decide that. I am looking for a way to do it in wsus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could block the updates that include the Get Windows 10 app in WSUS.

For Windows 7 SP1:

- KB3035583
- KB2952664

For Windows 8.1 Update:

- KB3035583
- KB2976978

(I got those [here](http://techdows.com/2015/06/how-to-enable-get-windows-10-app-icon-windows-7-or-8-1-taskbar.html).)

If you've already approved them, you might be able to decline them and roll them back.

That doesn't block them from the web page, but you might be able to block that page at the firewall.

Comment: seems you are right: i am now rejecting the followings: If you are using Windows 7: kb3035583, kb2952664, kb3021917
If you are using Windows 8: kb3035583, kb2976978

Answer (score 0):

In short: take away administrative privileges from your users.

> Wish I was the one that could decide that.

Unfortunately that is the answer to your question. Even if you disabled this in WSUS, there are still many other mechanisms your users could use to upgrade if they wanted to. WSUS is not meant to enforce policy.

If you want to enforce policy, you'll need to use Active Directory and Group Policy. With those two technologies in place, doing what you want becomes trivial.